# Implement dynamic propTypes in ReactJs component

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, react-proptypes

I have an object with icons available to some button.

```
const icons = {
  check: 'icon-CheckSmall',
  chat: 'icon-ChatMedium',
  investors: 'icon-InvestorsMedium',
  download: 'icon-DownloadMedium',
};

const Button = (props) => {
  const {
    buttonType,
    buttonText,
    onClick,
    disabled,
  } = props;

  return (
    <button
      style={ icons }
      type={ buttonType }
      onClick={ onClick }
      disabled={ disabled && 'disabled' }
    >
        { <FormattedMessage id={ buttonText } /> }
    </button>
  );
};
```

I want to create prop types for component with keys array

```
Button.propTypes = {
  icon: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.keys(icons)),
};
```

In this case, `Object.keys` does not work.

Is there anyone who manage to implement dynamic prop types in the component?